# Is there any way to make code organized if I have a super long list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to avoid single lines containing thousands of characters if I happen to have a super long list?

Comment: HI, welcome. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good resource for learning to ask a great question, giving a intro, and a concrete example would help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take a list with many values and break it down, Try this

```
mylist = [
    value,
    value2,
    value3,
    ]
```

If you have a list of stings that are very long, you can create multi-line strings with `'''My String'''`. E.g.

```
mylist = [
    '''A Very very
    long String''',
    '''Another Very
    very
    very
    very long string''',
    ]
```

Read more [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: I think you want to use implicit string concatenation (`'...''...'`), since you are actually changing the data by inserting newlines in the middle of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
mylst = [1,2,3,4]
```

Is the same as

```
mylst = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
    ]
```

So, you can break your super long line into many lines.